# Header location to remain the same

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently creating a podcast website where I have a form for my users to enter a comment on the current episode they are listening to.

All my content is stored in mysql and data on my episode page is displayed like so

```
http://www.mysite.com/episode.php?id=1
```

With separate content for the episode.

On this post [adding to database no repeat on refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761367/adding-to-database-no-repeat-on-refresh)

I mentioned about the form resubmitting on refresh which is why I added

```
header('Location: index.php');
```

However. I would like this to visit the same page with a thank you message echoed.

I have tried

```
header('Location: episode.php?id=<?php echo $data['cast_id']; ?>');
echo "thank you";
```

But this brings back the error **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING**

Please can someone advise me on the best way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: header('Location: episode.php?id='.$data['cast_id']); please try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
header('Location: episode.php?id=<?php echo $data['cast_id']; ?>');
```

you are using php tags in already started php tags.

you can simply do this ..

```
session_start(); // make sure session is up and running
// just before redirecting 

$_SESSION['thankyou_msg'] = 1;
    header('Location: episode.php?id='.$data['cast_id']);

now on index.php.


session_start(); 

if(isset($_SESSION['thankyou_msg'])){
   echo "your thankyou message here";
   unset($_SESSION['thankyou_msg']);
}
```

Comment: Thank you but my echo does not display

Comment: use session to show thankyou notification. i ahve updated my ans so that you can have an idea

Answer (score 1):

`header()` function is php function, so why you start php in it?
Also add `exit()` and store message in `SESSION` variable.

```
$_SESSION['msg'] = "thank you";
header("Location: episode.php?id=$data['cast_id']");
exit();
```

Comment: Thank you but my echo message as shown in my edit of the original post does not display. Any ideas why?

Comment: @kevstarlive php execute code line by line, header redirect you to episode.php so execution stop there, all code after header does not show. better way is store message in SESSION before header redirect. and add `exit()` after header